# Decrease polyline smoothly in realtime - flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am able to animate the marker using the TickerProviderStateMixin class but for polyline, I don't want that when the user changes his location after that I call the directions API again to get the new polyline points, and update it to show on the Google map. I want that without calling the API again and again I should be able to smoothly decrease the poyline like the Google Map mobile app when using it for directions.

So once I get the polyline points using the Google Directions map api then I show the polyline on the map and after that, if the user moves from his current location towards the destination location the polyline slowly decreases instead of instantly without calling the google map direction API again and again.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to improve your chances of getting help and so that the community ca help you better with your concern.